# How can I fetch the postgres database to pyhton?

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5

I have a widget for user id, if you input a a user id it will read all the data from the postgres and display the data which is the name, username, password, verified password to the specific widget.heres my code

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import psycopg2

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(733, 772)
        
        

    def search_user_data(self):
        user_id = self.textuserid.text()

        # Connect to the database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host="localhost",
            database="user_access profil",
            user="postgres",
            password="12345"
        )

        cursor = conn.cursor()

       
        sql_query = f'SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_id={user_id}'

        try:
            cursor.execute(sql_query)
            user_data = cursor.fetchone()

            if user_data:
                # User ID exists, display the rest of the data
                self.display_user_data(user_data)
            else:
                # User ID not found, handle accordingly (e.g., show a message)
                print("User ID not found")

        except psycopg2.Error as e:
            print(f"Error fetching data: {e}")

        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()

    def display_user_data(self, user_data):
      
    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Is there a question here that we might help you answer?

Comment: How to fetch data from the database? After fetching I will search the user id and display the name, usernae,password.

Comment: With a database you should not need to search after fetching, you should create a query that only returns the single record you're looking for.

Comment: Are you not already fetching the data with `user_data = cursor.fetchone()`?

Comment: Yesss will fetch the user_id but I need to display the name, username, and password to that user

Comment: 1) You need to read this [Parameter Passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for why this `f'SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_id={user_id}'` is a security hole. 2) You need to read this [Cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) for how to work with cursors. 3) Lastly read this [Cursor subclasses](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#cursor-subclasses) for the different cursor outputs you can get.

Comment: As an unrelated note, there probably was an important warning in the header of that file you're using, which clearly says that you should **not** edit it unless you know what you're doing. pyuic generated files should **never** be modified, instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Finally, it's not clear if the problem is about fetching data or showing it in the UI. In the second case, you need to clarify what type of data, and what widgets you're using, but most importantly show us your *attempts* in doing it.